# Horror movie with two girls, one of whom is a monster who tries to kill the other in a pool

Tags: story-identification, horror

I don't remember much of it because I was so young when I watched it but it’s a horror movie.

I'm pretty sure it's based in a high school. The scene I remember looks like it was in a high school gym swimming pool, and there are two girls. One is some sort of monster and tries to kill her in the pool (the monster girl can transform) then the other girl gets out of the pool somehow and eventually makes her way behind the grand stand and the monster girl follows, turns into some monster thing and the other girl crushes the monster with the grand stand?

That's all I can remember.

Comment: Can you give us some idea of when you watched it? That will help narrow it down.

Comment: There's no grandstand or transforming as I can recall, but [Jennifer's Body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jennifer%27s_Body) has a monster, high school girls and a pool, I think.

Comment: probably the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/233298/film-where-aliens-invade-high-school (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Comment: another pool/monster/teenager (more like middle school age) movie was Let Me In -- Chloe Moretz is a vampire who looks like a kid.

Answer (score 28):

This is probably *[The Faculty](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0133751/)*. From the [Wikipedia summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Faculty):

> Casey returns to the gym, where Marybeth reveals herself to be the queen, having faked taking the test earlier. She attacks Stokes, who is stunned at the revelation. **Casey and Stokes flee to the swimming pool where Stokes is injured and infected.** Zeke and Casey go to the locker room, where Marybeth reverts to her human disguise, naked. She explains that she is taking over Earth because her own planet is dying. **Marybeth transforms back to the queen** and renders Zeke unconscious by throwing him into a locker. Casey takes the drug and **tricks the queen into following him into the retracting bleachers, thus trapping her**. Casey then stabs the drug into the queen's eye to kill it.

[image: Cover image]

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at the movie *Jennifer's Body*. I remember Megan Fox trying to kill Amanda Seyfried in a pool.