# Film where aliens invade high school

Tags: story-identification, movie

I need to find a film that I watched in 2000-2010.

I remember the invasion started in a high school football stadium. A group of teenagers figure it out and run home. People look normal but get mind controlled. They know the city got attacked and the thing to defend themselves is a drug(or a substance) they usually use.

I also remember the group has about 5-7 people. They try to escape the city but eventually get discovered. At the end of the day, the group only had 2 people left and end up going to the stadium. They hide and figure out there is a queen-like creature in the stadium and try to use the last dose to kill it. Then one goes out and later comes back to their hideout but the other isn't sure that he(she) isn't controlled.

That is all the plot I can remember. Please help me find it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is the 1998 film [The Faculty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Faculty), about a group of six teenagers who defend their town from mind-controlling alien parasites. One of the main characters is a football player, and a major scene takes place at a high school football game. There is also a scene where the teenagers snort a homemade powdered drug in order to demonstrate that none of them are infected, since the drug has been demonstrated to kill or injure the alien parasites.

During the final portion of the movie, the teenagers take shelter in their high school gymnasium. One of the characters does leave the gym and when he returns the others are unsure whether he has been infected. The alien queen is later killed in the gym.

Comment: I will watch it tonight and come back if it is what I need, Thanks a lot

Comment: Featuring Frodo, Jean Grey, the T-1000 and Usher!